# Detecting Batch File From Users PC

Tags: batch-file

Our owners have a batch file to access the C: drive on anybodies computer, is there a way for the user to detect that the batch file is running and their C: drive is currently being accessed by another user? I want to cover all bases and unfortunately I didnt know the answer to this.

Comment: The drives could be mapped, there could be remote control software running.  These things may be permanent features and presumably the owners have a right to be monitoring the machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below command from cmd prompt if you know the name of the child process that runs in your computer.

```
   tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq processname.exe" 2>NUL
```